# Different approaches to an allocation algorithm for processes?

Tags: algorithm, resources

I am looking to implement an automated way of allocating processes to a variety of servers available. There are many types of servers (characterized by things like location, cpu, network card, etc..) and there are various types of processes (more than there are servers) with different priorities and location/hardware requirements. I can think of pretty much greedy algorithms that are simplistic in nature but was wondering what other references and approaches exist for this type of problem (which I feel is pretty standard). I am also interested in solving a related problem - in which say we remove one of the servers after things have been allocated and we need to reshuffle with minimal interference. This latter one I also feel is standard but I'm not sure what some good references to look at are. Any suggestions on where to start?

Comment: Are you looking for a static or dynamic algorithm? If you're looking for a dynamic algorithm, do you you know for how long would each process run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague. Normally problems like this are handled either by modeling them as a set of linear equations and optimizing an *objective function* given the linear constraints, or the problem is modeled as a knapsack problem.